# Clicked on this script from a SSD I bought second hand. Is it malicious?

Tags: vbscript

I clicked without thinking and it didn't appear to do anything but shut the windows. Looking at the code I'm too noob to work out what it does but I'm paranoid it's done something behind the scenes.

```
Option Explicit

'On Error Resume Next

Dim strComputer
Dim objWmiService
Dim colMonitoredProcesses
Dim objLatestProcess

Dim colProcesses
Dim objProcess

strComputer = "."

Set objWmiService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
    & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colProcesses = objWmiService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * From Win32_Process Where Name = 'explorer.exe'")

For Each objProcess In colProcesses
    objProcess.Terminate
Next

Set colMonitoredProcesses = objWmiService.ExecNotificationQuery _
    ("Select * From __InstanceCreationEvent " _
    & "Within 1 Where TargetInstance Isa 'Win32_Process' " _
    & "And (TargetInstance.Name = 'iexplore.exe' " _
    & "Or TargetInstance.Name = 'notepad.exe')")

Do 

    Set objLatestProcess = _
    colMonitoredProcesses.NextEvent.TargetInstance

    If LCase(objLatestProcess.Name) = "iexplore.exe" Then
        objLatestProcess.Terminate
    End If

Loop
```

Comment: A) Don't click on random scripts. B) Format drives you get like this to avoid catching something ugly.

Comment: This script closes internet explorer and  notepad windows (terminates the processes), so in a way, it isn't nice, because you might loose your unsaved data, but it is not a virus and doesn't cause any serious damage. Just don't use it again

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might be some code that "waits for a process to start, terminates the process and exits when it sees a particular process start."

(Essentially, it just closes notepad and internet explorer processes, it seems)

Here's a [link to a blog post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/178ad9b9-d3b2-4b41-976c-f38bf09f2eb8/background-vbscript-that-waits-for-a-process-to-start-terminates-the-process-and-exits-when-it-sees?forum=ITCG) on a Microsoft forum with *almost* exactly that code.

([Background vbscript that waits for a process to start, terminates the process and exits when it sees a patricular process start](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/178ad9b9-d3b2-4b41-976c-f38bf09f2eb8/background-vbscript-that-waits-for-a-process-to-start-terminates-the-process-and-exits-when-it-sees?forum=ITCG))

I think you are ok!

In the future don't click random stuff!

Answer (score 0):

First it closes all `explorer.exe` instances (this is the Windows shell, basically taskbar and desktop). It then watches for Notepad or Internet Explorer to start and if it's Internet Explorer, shuts it down. Why it is also checking for Notepad to start but not doing anything, I don't know.